# Change syntax using regular expression

Tags: sql, regex, pattern-matching

I have some inherited legacy language code snippets stored in a database table that I need to transform to a SQL like syntax so it can be used more effectively.

For example, one of the snippets is of the form

```
keyword = [a,b,c,x:y,d,e,f,p:q]
```

to indicate either discrete comma separate values or a range of colon-delimited values

How can I transform this to the equivalent SQL friendly snippet which would be

```
keyword in (a,b,c) or keyword between x and y or keyword in (d,e,f) or keyword between p and q
```

Thanks

Comment: In case you're hoping to do it in a single regex replacement: you most probably can't since with most tools/languages you can only replace a pattern with a single replacement string. You can't "say" replace `patternA` with `replacementA` but replace `patternB` with `replacementB`. So, what tool are you going to use for these replacements?

Answer (score 0):

It isn't regex but the first this that comes to mind it extracting the text within the square brackets so you have

```
textVariable  = a,b,c,x:y,d,e,f,p:q
```

then split with the columns so you have an array where each element is part of the string. So your resulting array would be

```
array[0] = a
...
array[3] = x:y
...
```

Then go through your array and create the final string you want. something like this (though it isn't tested)

```
finalString = ""
tempString = ""
for (int i = 0, i < array.length; i++) {
   if (array[i].contains(":")) { // then it needs to be between the two values
      if (finalString.length > 0) {
         finalString = finalString + " or "; // need to add an 'or'
      }
      if (tempString.length > 0) { // then need to add the keyword in (...) to finalString
         finalString = finalString + tempString + ") or ";
      }
      temparray = array[i].split(":")
      finalString = finalString + " keyword between " + temparray[0] + " and " + temparray[1]
   } else {
      if (tempString.length = 0) {
         tempString= "keyword in ("; // need to start the next set
      } else {
         tempString = tempString + ", "
      }
      tempString = tempString + array[i];
   }
}
```

Comment: I was hoping using regular expressions would lead to a more succinct solution rather than boring old string parsing. :-) 

The keyword and each value/range of values could be captured in a sub-expression and the replacement string could replay the expression using either IN or BETWEEN depending on whether the captured value has/doesn't have a colon.

Thanks :-)

Comment: No problem.. It was just want I thought up first. Figured it would be better than nothing. :)

Comment: I sometimes think that the less people know about regex, the more they think it can do for them! :)